# Add TimeDelta to Date in Python C API

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I have two objects:

```
#include <datetime.h>
#include <Python.h>
....
PyObject *first_date = PyDate_FromDate(2022, 08, 31);
PyObject *time_delta = PyDelta_FromDSU(2, 0, 0);
```

How can i subtract `time_delta` from `first_date`?
As i found, there is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_datetimemodule.c
with methods i need but i can not import it from my main file

Answer (score 1):

```
PyObject* Date = PyDate_FromDate(year, month, day);
PyObject* TimeDelta = PyDelta_FromDSU(days, seconds, microseconds);

PyObject* result = PyNumber_Add(Date, TimeDelta);
```

You should do like these...